# Issues when trying to copy one char array to another (without using already existing functions)

Tags: c++, function, char

I am currently stuck on copying one char array to another char array. When I try to do so I end up cutting off most of one array and receiving "ed." as a result which is the last 3 characters of my arr2[]. I am not allowed to use built in functions, so I'm trying to do this by scratch but I'm facing the problem mentioned. Any tips?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Print.h"


using namespace std;

void Copy(char arr1[], char arr2[]);

int main(){

    char arr1[] = {"Hello how are you? \0 hiii"};
    char arr2[] = { "The weather was cloudy today, so it rained. \0" };
    char arr3[] = { "Coffee is a great way to start the day. \0" };

    Print(arr1);

    Copy(arr2, arr3);

}
void Copy(char cloud[], char coffee[]){

        while (*coffee != '\0')
        {
            *cloud = *coffee++;
            ++cloud;
        }

        cout << cloud << endl;

}
```

Comment: for another function that's in my program, it does not involve the problem, it prints out an array. I'm focused on trying to get my Copy() function to work.

Comment: You probably need to put an extra `'\0'` to terminate the string after copying. What you are doing is dangerous and error prone though.

Comment: At the end of the loop, `cloud` points to the end so `cout << cloud` is not useful

Comment: Also meaningful variable names like source and target would be more useful.

Answer (score 3):

> When I try to do so I end up cutting off most of one array and receiving "ed." as a result

This happens since you are incrementing both the variables in `Copy` AND you are not null terminating `cloud`.

My suggestion: use array indexing to copy the array.

```
void Copy(char cloud[], char coffee[])
{
   int i = 0;
   while ( coffee[i] != '\0' )
   {
      cloud[i] = coffee[i];
      ++i;
   }

   // Make sure to null terminate cloud
   cloud[i] = '\0';

   // This should produce the expected output.
   cout << cloud << endl;
}
```